# How to prevent copy of URL in Parent Window

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

In my application I am opening my application page in a Child Window. When I look these in IE, It doesnt show any URL this is great but When I check it in Firefox and Chrome I shows me URL.

My Question is Can I hide address bar in Child Window for Firefox and chrome.

I want to prevent User to copy paste URL in Parent window and access the page.

I m using form Authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="3600" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseUri" enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
    </authentication>
```

I have tried using Authorization="?"
I have tried using a javascript to check whether this is a parent window or child window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof window.opener != "undefined")
            alert("I was opened from within " + window.opener.location.href);
        else if (window != top)
            alert("You came here from " + document.referrer);
</script>
```

But the 2nd part is not working.
Kindly Help me and let me know what I m doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of preventing user to copy paste url what u can do is u can put some script, that can runs only when a request is made else it will do the action that you want.

```
 string referer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
        {
            Response.Redirect("../Index.htm");
        }
```

Use runs page only if request is coming from a page else it will redirect to the desired page

Answer (score 0):

No You cannot hide the url if you open a new window.
If the page is from the same domain, you can instead AJAX the result into a popup DIV on your current page.

That said - anyone with a tiny bit of web savvy, can find the URL anyway.

For example in Chrome I do not even have to install anything, just click "Inspect Element" hit the NET tab and see the url as it is loaded from whereever.

Comment: I dont want some one to copy paste the url. If he does so I want him to redirect to a user defined page
Does this make sense

Comment: It makes great sense. But you can't do it.

Comment: let me give an example that may help u to define my problem more accurately
https://www.obconline.co.in/ just check the checkbox and click on submit then a new window will open try copy pasting the URL in a new window.
and other thing I have done is disabled the right click

Comment: Because it doesn't belong to you. For instance, how will you prevent the user from running Fiddler or some other network monitoring tool to see exactly what URL the page comes from? You won't. Get used to the idea. The web is different from desktop application development, where you can control everything.

Comment: John go throuh this website obconline.co.in.
It show the URL but tell me what happens when u copy paste the URL in  a browser

Comment: _You have asked Firefox to connect
securely to obconline.co.in, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure._

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want right, the only way is after the use logs in, (since you have a login form), save a boolean in the session state that indicates that the user is authenticated, then in the page you want to hide it's url, at the page_load event, check if this boolean is true, this way you can limit access to this url without needing to hide the url.